# How come I cant get this Jquery alert to work in google chrome?

Tags: jquery, message, alert

So Im trying to just verify that my Jquery file is working by using an alert box but in google chorme it will not show the alert please any help and did I possibly download jquery wrong?
Here is the basic code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready.(function(){
      alert("I'm working!");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready.(function(){

alert("I'm working!");


});


</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Click the `edit` link just below your question's tags to put your code into your question.

Comment: Pretty sure that won't work with *any* browser with that rogue `.` in there. Plus, look at your console and see what error message it gives you.

Answer (score 6):

Take that period out after the `ready`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `.` "dot" after the `ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ alert("I'm working!"); })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2N6WK/